Why is "hidden dependency" (required things not in parameter list directly) a disadvantage of "global variables", but not in "preserve whole object"?
According to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/200092, as I know, "preserve whole object" is a refactor method that passes the whole object instead of required parameters only, for example, to show information of Student:
public class Student{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String internalId;
    //setters and getters
}

Pass required parameters only:
public void showStudentInfo(String name,int age){
    //show some dialog
} 

this.showStudentInfo(this.student.getName(),this.student.getAge());

Preserve whole object:
public void showStudentInfo(Student student){
    //show some dialog
} 

this.showStudentInfo(this.student);

However, after refactoring into "Preserve whole object", I found it has a drawback: I can't see which data fields does showStudentInfo() used directly (also for data fields that it doesn't use), which looks as if one of the disadvantage of "global state" that has "hidden dependency":
public void showStudentInfo(){
    String name=GlobalData.student.name;
    int age=GlobalData.student.age;
}

So my question is, why would "preserve whole object" be a refactor method despite it removes the data of the method that depends on? Or I misunderstood the term "hidden dependency" (which I think "hidden dependency" of a method means classes that don't appear directly in parameter list of a method that the method requires)?
And one more question with answer about it : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/277490, seems also thinks passing required parameters only is better

If you want to be explicit on which data fields the showStudentInfo method uses, have it take an interface StudentInfo { getName(): string; getAge(): int } instead of a concrete Student.

'GlobalData' is a hidden dependency because it is not passed to the function.

My primary issue is I can't see clearly if showStudentInfo() changes the student, I don't care what fields it reads.

Because the purpose of the method is defined on the level of the object (student), not the fields therein (name and age).
While your code might currently display students using their name and age, showStudentInfo(Student s) and showNameAndAge(string name, int age) are different methods with different purposes.
The purpose of the showStudentInfo is to, well, show the student's info. If tomorrow you decided that this also includes their student ID, then the method hasn't really changed its purpose, it has only changed its implementation of that purpose.
At its very core, a method signature (i.e. name and parameters) focuses on the purpose of the method (i.e. what does this method do?), whereas the method body focuses on the implementation of that purpose (i.e. how can we achieve what we want this method to do?)
If you were to using name/age parameters, what you'd be doing is saying that the purpose of the method is to display a name and an age.
Taking this to an extreme, what if names are printed in a very unique reusable way (e.g. UPPERCASE), and ages too (in their own unique way, e.g. as a binary number)? Well, you'd end up with something like:
public void ShowStudentInfo(Student s)
{
    ShowName(s.Name);
    ShowAge(s.Age);
}

Three methods, all with very different purposes and implementations.

ShowStudentInfo's purpose is to display a student's info. Its implementation consists of choosing which student fields to use. This method does not care how the fields get rendered, it only picks the fields that should be rendered (and passes them to the appropriate rendering method).
ShowName's purpose is to display a name in the unique way that names should be shown, its implementation being one that uppercases the string. This method does not care whether the name came from a student or not.
ShowAge's purpose is to display an age in the unique way that ages should be shown, its implementation being one that converts an integer into a stringified binary digit sequence. This method does not care whether the age came from a student or not.



which looks as if one of the disadvantage of "global state" that has "hidden dependency"

Global state is really wide. It can be pretty much everything under the sun.
By comparison, having a method take in a Student parameter still restricts that method to only being able to access Student properties. That's still decidedly more narrow than giving access to a global scope.
Furthermore, the implication here is that no one is selectively and partially hydrating the Student object based on their knowledge of what showStudentInfo is going to rely on. You're going to find that generally speaking a Student is going to be treated as an atomic data object that is fully hydrated, regardless of which methods rely on which Student properties.
You're not wrong that, in a sense, an input parameter and a dependency are the same thing on a technical level as far as the compiler cares. However, on a semantical level they represent very different roles and developers innately have different expectations on how to treat them and rely on them.


So my question is, why would "preserve whole object" be a refactor method

When you look at lists of "refactoring" transforms, it's not unusual to find transforms in both directions.
So as well as this transform that replaces several parameters with the whole object, there will probably be an opposite transform somewhere in the same list that replaces a whole object with several parameters.
The purpose of these lists is really to give names to those transforms, not to imply that rote application of all the transforms in the list will improve the code.
Indeed, the original point of "refactoring" was to alter the structure of the code (in relatively minor, mechanical ways) to make it more amenable to a substantial planned change.
There's no one ideal "factorisation" (if that's a word) of the code, which avoids every unfortunate quality or which makes it perfectly amenable to all possible substantial changes that may be desired in future.
So the way in which you refactor the code depends on what kind of change you're trying to prepare it for, and the code which results from refactoring may well involve a different set of compromises on qualities than the original code, but will be more capable of accomodating the intended change.

This! Or tl;dr: Just because you can appply a refactoring does not mean that you should :-).

If "Student" is a well-designed class - e.g. following the "SOLID" principles, then generally you do not need to worry about which parts of Student are accessed by a function.
The class / object encapsulates the concept well, and you are communicating the concept, not the implementation details.  As Flater says in his answer - you want to display a Student.  There is no "hidden" dependency - the function is dependent on Student very overtly.
This idea also insulates your function interface to potential future implementation detail changes in Student.  What if you find that a singular "name" is not good enough - you need first and last names, and potentially a list of middle names?  And then you discover that some cultures work differently and the concept of "first and last names" doesn't really apply?
If you pass "Student" - you are free to modify the implementation that eventually produces the singular output that is the "name" you want to display, without having to change the function signature, and that's quite useful.

First some context - these named refactorings (from Refactoring by Martin Fowler) aren't necessarily meant to tell you what's better design-wise, they are just things that you can do to transform your code in a stepwise fashion (without breaking it) on your way to the design you are after. Many refactorings in this catalogue have a dual refactoring that does the exact opposite (though not this particular one, I believe). All of them have pros and cons. When the book was written, you'd do these transformations manually; today, you have tools that can do many popular refactorings with one click. You may apply various refactorings to arrive to a design you already know you want, but their non-destructive nature also allows you to try out a bunch of different things in hopes of sort of stumbling into a better design, assuming the current one is not working for you.
That said, you generally want to minimize the number of places where you are repeating code that should be kept in sync. Assuming you can confine any computation that actually uses name, age and other student fields to showStudentInfo(Student student) or similar methods, then such methods will likely be called in more places compared to the number of direct accesses to name and age (which would happen inside these methods). So if you need to modify the Student class, there are only a few places that need to be updated, compared to what you'd have to do if you had to update every call site.
Another advantage is that you're more closely modeling what the actual function is supposed to represent ("show info for this student"). Also, the design is kind of constrained in a way that makes the function easy to use correctly and hard to use incorrectly. While showStudentInfo(Student student) only accepts student objects,  showStudentInfo(String name, int age) is a more open-ended method that you can call with arbitrary parameters: showStudentInfo("Porsche 911", 8). That's fun (unless you do it by accident), but such lower-level methods belong somewhere deeper in the code, where they'd perhaps serve a more generic purpose, with the appropriate change in the name showBasicInfo(String name, int age), or something like that.
Having showStudentInfo(Student student) helps insure correctness to some extent, and in a compiled language, the compiler will prevent you from doing silly things. So this particular refactoring makes sense in the higher level code, but for the lower level, more generic code, you might decide against it.
Now, your Student class is really just a data structure, but in OOP, the object that you preserve as a whole to pass in as a parameter might have behaviors associated with it, so you wouldn't necessarily be accessing any fields on it at all (it might not even provide that option), you'd be delegating work to it by calling some of its methods. So there are designs that use this technique that are potentially very different than what you were envisioning.
Also, going down this path is not the only option. There could be cases where you don't want to pass individual low-level parameters, cases where you still want the correctness-friendly kind of design discussed above, but you also don't want to pass the entire Student object (maybe it doesn't make conceptual sense, maybe you don't want to allow access to all features of the class, etc). So you introduce a new concept - maybe an independent new type that you can create from a student instance, or maybe you introduce a base class that Student will derive from, so that you can make use of polymorphism.

Or I misunderstood the term "hidden dependency" (which I think "hidden
dependency" of a method means classes that don't appear directly in
parameter list of a method that the method requires)?

Software design is about battling complexity, about minimizing the number of things that you have to keep in mind while looking at a piece of code within a particular context. Passing in a whole object is more about "I don't have to think about the details of that function while I'm looking at the code that calls it". As in, you know what that function does at a high level (the same way you know what some library function does, without knowing how it does it), you know where all the inputs are coming from, and you know what sorts of output you can expect. showStudentInfo(Student student) takes in a student and shows the student info; no surprises there1, even though you don't know what it does with the student object internally.
A hidden global dependency is more like "something unexpected happened when I made the call; suddenly this other 'unrelated' thing over there doesn't work, and now I have to fire up the debugger and hope I'm lucky enough for the bug to happen again, so I can figure out what on Earth is going on". Or maybe these other parts of the system appear to be fine, but the function that you called sometimes doesn't work correctly, apparently without rhyme or reason.
In other words, a function accessing a global is the same as it having an additional non-obvious input value that you yourself didn't supply at the call site, that can change in unpredictable ways, affecting the behavior of the callee, and possibly of other parts of the system that are accessing (and maybe modifying) the same global.

1 "no surprises there" - well, almost. The "show" in the name implies the call will produce some output to the screen, probably via the standard output (like Console.WriteLine in C# or System.out.println in Java), and these are globals, with a global state. This is often of no concern, but it can make it difficult get the desired behavior in the terminal if you're trying to do something more complex than sequential printouts.

Simple explanation: the properties and functions of a complex object are (a) generally confined to that instance, and (b) can be known or discovered simply by looking at the signature and object definition.
Global values are neither of those things.  While you could of course have a complex object that uses a global variable as a backing field of a property, that is still better than using a global inside the method.
Ideally, given a type name and method signature (name and parameters), someone semi-knowledgeable about your application should have good odds of being able to tell you what it does, what it will use to do that as well as what it effects, even if they have never looked at the type let alone the specific method before.
